# Access data from the user that is logged in in an Outlook Module Extension

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365

In an Outlook module extension, can you access any of the information from the user that is logged in currently and use it in the add-in? If so, how? I know it's possible in normal add-ins but the context of a Module Extension is different (because there is no item opened)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed no context to check a specific item in the Outlook Module Extension in the add-in API. It is perfectly possible to get the user context and their login token, with those you can then use something like the EWS (Exchange Web Services) API or Office 365 (e.g. Graph/Outlook) APIs to retrieve any of the calendar/mail items in a user's Exchange/Office365 account.

In other words you **do** have a user context but you **don't** have an item context.